# Updating a foreign key in Entity Framework without separate id property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have setup an entity which looks like this:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Test2 Test2 { get; set; }
    //and some other fields
}
```

`test2` is another test object, with no navigation properties:

```
public partial class Test2
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I don't have a model builder setup in the context, it just has `DbSet` properties for `test` and `test2`.

And I'm attempting to update a row in the database from an unattached object that I create based on user input. In this test case the `Test2` property is null, and I am trying to update it to 3:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using(var context = new db.Model1())
    {
        var test = new db.Test();

        // we know id 1 exists for this simple test case
        test.Id = 1;

        // fake user input is 3 for test2 id
        test.Test2 = context.Test2.Where(x => x.Id == 3).FirstOrDefault();

        context.Test.Attach(test);
        context.Entry(test).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The issue is that this doesn't change the `Test_Id` column in the database to 3. What am I missing?

I have determined that if instead of creating the test object using `new()`, I query it from the context and then update, it works fine (shown below):

```
var test = context.Test.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);
test.Test2 = context.Test2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Why does my first approach not work if I am attaching the object to the context and setting its state to modified? Can I get away with not having a separate `test2_id` field for the foreign key relationship, which seems redundant?

Comment: What if you start tracking the object before changing the `Test2` value?

Comment: Interesting... I moved the attach call to under the line where I set test.id = 1, and an exception was generated!  "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose a foreign key property for their relations..." i'm looking into the details.